# Getting length of names in Java with nextLine()

Tags: java, string, input, output, string-length

I am very new to Java. I'm in my first Java class and we are just working on the basics. I am supposed to write a program that prompts the user to enter their first, middle, and last name with spaces. Then display the length of the first name, the length of the middle name, the initials, and the full name in all upper case. Here is the class example

Example Output:

```
Enter a first name middle name and surname
Peggy Sue Palmer

Length of your name: 16 characters

Length of your middle name: 3 characters

Your initials are PSP

PEGGY SUE PALMER
```

I have worked on some code so far and I am able to get some of the output correctly but when I go to enter Peggy Sue Palmer I have to input the name one at a time with a space at the end and then press enter to input the next name. Also it displays the length of the middle initial as 4 instead of 3. I know that I can have the input all on one line by just having one input String name = input.nextLine(), which allows the input format I am looking for but if I do that I have no clue how to get the length of the middle name or the initials. Sorry this is a dumb question but this is my first Java class and we are just learning the basics.

```
package tracy2prog1;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Tracy2prog1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //create new scanner class
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    //prompt user to enter first middle and last name
    System.out.println("Please enter your first middle and last name with spaces between them");
    String firstname = input.nextLine();
    String middlename = input.nextLine();
    String lastname = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println(firstname.length() + middlename.length() + lastname.length());
    System.out.println("The length of your middle name is " + middlename.length() + " characters");
    System.out.println("Your initials are " + firstname.charAt(0) + middlename.charAt(0) +lastname.charAt(0));
    System.out.println(firstname.toUpperCase() + middlename.toUpperCase() + lastname.toUpperCase());

  }

 }
```

Here is the updated code that works, only issue is its not counting the spaces in the output of the full name to 16, I am getting 14.

```
package tracy2prog2;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Tracy2prog2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //create new scanner class
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            //prompt user to enter first middle and last name
            System.out.println("Please enter your first middle and last name with spaces between them");
            String firstname = input.next();
            String middlename = input.next();
            String lastname = input.next();
            System.out.print("Your name is ");
            System.out.println(firstname.length() + middlename.length() + lastname.length() + " characters");
            System.out.println("The length of your middle name is " + middlename.length() + " characters");
            System.out.println("Your initials are " + firstname.charAt(0) + middlename.charAt(0) +lastname.charAt(0));
            System.out.println(firstname.toUpperCase() + " " + middlename.toUpperCase() + " " + lastname.toUpperCase());


}
```

}

Comment: `input.nextLine().split(" ");` Also `firstName.trim().length()` will not hurt.

Comment: Read the entire name entered with spaces, then split the input into your 3 variables (firstname, middlename, lastname). Or split into an array as in above comment, but you may not have gotten to arrays yet. Then do your string manipulations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at how you can do it (one of many examples) - Maybe this will help you in the future, as you probably don't know arrays yet (I didn't know you were in your first class, I went to the problem before reading all - don't do that by the way, sorry!)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tracy2prog1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create new scanner class
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //prompt user to enter first middle and last name
        System.out.println("Please enter your first middle and last name with spaces between them");

        //Here you will have your names without " ", then its length is 2 characters shorter
        String[] names = input.nextLine().split(" ");

        //As your names are in an array now, you can get then directly
        System.out.println(names[0].length() + names[1].length() + names[2].length());
        System.out.println("The length of your middle name is " + names[1].length() + " characters");
        System.out.println("Your initials are " + names[0].charAt(0) + names[1].charAt(0) +names[2].charAt(0));
        System.out.println(names[0].toUpperCase() + " " + names[1].toUpperCase() + " " + names[2].toUpperCase());

        //Peggy Sue Palmer
        //Considering you did this: String[] names = input.nextLine().split(" ");
        //your array is ["Peggy", "Sue", "Palmer"]
        //then array[0] is "Peggy"
        //then "Peggy".length == 5
        //plus: names[0].charAt(0) means "Peggy".charAt(0) which is "P"
        System.out.println("The length of your first name is " + names[0].length() + " characters");
        System.out.println("The initial of your first name is " + names[0].charAt(0));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have to input the name one at a time with a space at the end and then press enter to input the next name.

Let's look at how you get the name:

```
String firstname = input.nextLine();
String middlename = input.nextLine();
String lastname = input.nextLine();
```

You are reading three separate lines here which is why you have to press enter between each part of the name. Instead you should read the entire name at once:

```
String name = input.nextLine();
```

Now you need to parse the name into separate pieces. I'll leave this for you to figure out how to do. You should look at [the documentation of the `String` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to find any functions which might be helpful to finish solving the problem.

Comment: I found a solution as we have not made it to arrays in the class yet. My only question now is that when it outputs the length of the full name it is not counting the spaces, it tells me 14 instead of 16. The teacher did not specify to count the spaces but I am assuming so since his answer in the example is 16. Is there a way to have the program notice the spaces without changing my code to split(" ") since we have not encountered that yet.

Comment: @B.Moe09 I assume you are adding together the length of the first, middle, and last names. Since you assume that the input is always a 3-part name, you can just add 2 to the total because you can assume that there will always be 2 spaces.

Comment: Thank you very much